# Who is the strongest fusion, Gogeta super saiyan blue or Vegito super saiyan blue?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Dragon Ball Super Broly shows,

> Gogeta defeating Broly

About Broly it is said

> He might be stronger than Beerus

If you consider these facts alone you could think Gogeta is stronger than Vegito but, of course, you can think Goku and Vegeta got stronger since before the tournament of power to the time they fought Broly. How about other clues in the series, movies, manga, official guides about Vegito and Gogeta's strenght? Who is the strongest fusion, Gogeta super saiyan blue or Vegito super saiyan blue?

Comment: It depends completely, but if each fusion, given an equal base Goku and base Vegeta, were trying to push their power to max, then Gogeta would be more powerful since his half-hour of time was not burned out by Blue, where Vegito's hour of time was reduced to about three minutes of pushing it at Blue... and the base Goku and Vegeta used when Gogeta went blue were a lot more powerful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I believe you are comparing the Vegito from the *Future Trunks arc* and the Gogeta Blue from the *Dragon Ball Super movie*? Then yes! **Gogeta Blue is definitely stronger**. The reasons being, for one, Goku and Vegeta have gotten significantly stronger throughout the T.O.P, in comparison to the Future Trunks arc. Secondly, irrespective of whether Broly is stronger than Beerus, his power has been compared to a *God of destruction*. I do understand Shin made a comment in the manga about Vegito rivaling Beerus in the Future Trunks arc, however, I honestly am not going  to consider it simply on account of the number of inaccurate statements we have seen from Shin throughout the series(He thought SSJG Goku might defeat Beerus, SSJB Vegeta was winning against Jiren, Vegeta might lose against Pui Pui and the list goes on).
Also in the anime, there is an alternate Corrupted version of Merged Zamasu who is significantly stronger. Beerus comments he'd be able to easily defeat Merged Zamasu(Who was going toe to toe with Vegito Blue). Jiren's power was compared to that of a G.O.D and Beerus being one of the strongest G.O.D's should rival Jiren(At least before he releases his dormant power) and Jiren even before he releases his dormant power, is in a way implied to be stronger than Vegito considering the fact that Goku and Vegeta didn't resort to fusion to challenge Jiren and it was heavily implied Goku would have to master UI to win.
Now suppose we have an alternate reality where Goku and Vegeta fuse into Vegito instead of Gogeta in the movie, I believe Vegito would be stronger simply because the Potara Fusion has been stated to be more powerful. The Potara earrings are owned by the highest beings of the universe. The Supreme Kais and the traditional fusion dance was created by a bunch of mortals.

Comment: Sorry, what I want to compare is both fusions if  base characters would be at the same level. For example, if in the Broly movie Goku and Vegeta would do the potara fusion, would they be stronger or week than Vegito? True that I mentioned Vegito from Dragon Ball Super and that base characters were weaker before but for comparison purpose. You might want to edit your answer now that I've clarified that

Comment: @Pablo Your question seems a little misleading. This is because, you go on to state how "Gogeta is stronger than Vegito but, of course, you can think Goku and Vegeta got stronger since before the tournament of power to the time they fought Broly."  Because if the question is with regard to whether Gogeta or Vegito would be stronger at any given time, the only thing that ultimately matters is the fusion dance vs the potara fusion and the potara fusion has been indicated to be stronger.

Comment: IIRC, the Potaro will always be either equal to or stronger than the fusion dance because for the fusion dance, the stronger of the two must lower his power level to match the other, while for potaro this is not necessary. This means the fusion dance is a sum of one full strength and one sub-full strength, and potaro is the sum of two full strength.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually stated in the Fusion Saga by the Elder Kai that the Potara Earring fusion is much stronger than some silly dance. This is why Goku is still on the God Planet before warping to earth. It's also supposed to be a permanent fusion, and fusing while super saiyan would shorten the lifespan of the fighters. The fusion dance on the other hand, adds the fighters powers and abilities together and does increase it-just not as much as Potara. The earrings have the drawback of supposedly being permanent, but the advantage of far greater power.

Goten + Trunks = weaker than Fat Buu. 
Goten + Trunks fusion = strong enough to beat Super Buu
Super Buu > Fat Buu

Mystic Fused Buu > Goku + Vegetta
Goku + Vegetta fusion = probably same level as Mystic Fused Buu
Goku + Vegetta Potara Fusion = far superior to Mystic Fused Buu(as in a joke)